# how to create snowflake schema from this database?

Tags: data-warehouse, snowflake-schema, star-schema-datawarehouse

i try to create a snowflake schema from this: [image]

and I try to make that so please help me for develop my snow Flake schema and tell me what is wrong in this and how to make it better ....
[image]

Comment: It would help if you used consistent notation (i.e. consistently use crowsfoot). and also indicated PK's. I'm guessing that a single `item` record has many `info_table` records? If that's the case then this is not a snowflake schema. The usual way to fix this is pivot `info_table` into a single record per item and add it as columns to the `items` table. Yes I know this is difficult because `info_id` is variable but thats what is necessary to build a star or snowflake schema.

Comment: thanks for your answer .... you mean that i change it to that ? --->                         item[ item_id , item_name,sell_price,item_type , description , available quantity]

Comment: That diagram is more consistent now. In your diagram, all relationships going out from the facts are many to one and that's fine.

Comment: But there is no reason to have order date sitting out there in it's own table (order_table). Move it into `fact_Table` Otherwise you have to join two enormous tables everytime. The other thing is.... star schema is better than snowflake schema. So unless you have been explicitly asked to create a snowflake schema, you could model this with just four tables and it would be much simpler.

Comment: You've tagged star schema... always aim for a star schema and only use a snowflake schema if you have to.

Comment: thanks for your help i fix that thank u so much and i update the picture  , so i must create snowflake schema i will remove this tag ... now i must to add one other table, right? so what you offer to me :(  what table i must to add

Comment: What makes you think you need to add one other table? This question is pretty backwards which makes me think it's a tutorial question.... which is fine, it just has no practical application.